# SELinux - Prevent users in the user_t domain from creating sockets

Tags: security, selinux

I need untrusted users to execute Ruby and Python scripts via SSH on a Fedora 17 machine with a minimal impact on system integrity and security.

A SSH wrapper will ensure only Ruby and Python executables will be run(directly).

User's home dir (as well as /tmp) are not executable(Ruby and Python run from /usr).

Need to prohibit users to create sockets.

As well as any recommendations on how to minimize the damage caused by evildoers.

Thank you.